# Modify the href attribute of <a> tag dynamically in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, javascript

Im using Calculated Form Fields plugin for a Wordpress website. I already created the form I needed, but now I need to add the calculated price from the form as a URL parameter dynamically, when the button bellow the form is clicked.

The website uses Visual Composer and this is the button html:

```
<a class="nectar-button medium accent-color has-icon regular-button" target="_blank" href="https://na2.docusign.net/member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=df6fbf3d-6f5d-4c48-8965-f4fa810099f4&amp;Institutional_Buyer_AnnualPrice=15000"><span>Purchase Kuali Ready</span></a>
```

I want to change the "Institutional_Buyer_AnnualPrice=15000" part of the URL to be added/changed dynamically, according to what is the price in the field. And this is my current JavaScript code:

```
(function($) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("nectar-button").onclick = function() {
        var link = document.getElementsByClassName("nectar-button");
        var price = $('#fieldname9_1').val();
        link.setAttribute('href','https://na2.docusign.net/member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=df6fbf3d-6f5d-4c48-8965-f4fa810099f4&Institutional_Buyer_AnnualPrice=' + price);
         return false;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the link of the page: https://www.kuali.co/products/kuali-ready-online-purchasing/

I`ve already tried the solutions of like 3-4 questions about the same topic I found on Stackoverflow, but none of them works for me, thats why I wrote the question to wordpress.stackexchange.com

p.s. Please ignore the fact that making the js code work will affect all the buttons created with Visual Composer for now.

Comment: You are calling the element by class name. This will return an array of items. Try using ID instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (pure JavaScript):

```
var allBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('nectar-button');

function preventDefaultOpenCustomUrl(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var price = document.getElementById("fieldname9_1").value;
    var url = 'https://na2.docusign.net/member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=df6fbf3d-6f5d-4c48-8965-f4fa810099f4&Institutional_Buyer_AnnualPrice=' + price;
    window.open(url);
}
;

for (i = 0; i < allBtns.length; i++) {
    allBtns[i].addEventListener("click", preventDefaultOpenCustomUrl);
}
```

this is adding the event to all buttons with that `classname`,
with Jquery:

```
(function ($) {
    $('.nectar-button').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var price = $('#fieldname9_1').val();
        var url = 'https://na2.docusign.net/member/PowerFormSigning.aspx?PowerFormId=df6fbf3d-6f5d-4c48-8965-f4fa810099f4&Institutional_Buyer_AnnualPrice=' + price;
        window.open(url);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

if you dont have access to the HTML to add an ID you can use more tags/classnames in the `selector` to select that specific button.

Comment: You don't know if he doesn't have another button with the same class name on his page.

Comment: Doesnt work, did you mean to remove (function($) {})(jQuery);?

Comment: About other buttons, If I manage to make it work, I will put an id to the button and use getElementById as I mentioned in the post

Comment: You can't ignore that. This function will not work until you correctly call the right button.

Comment: There are 2 more buttons at the end of the page, I dont know why visual composer doesnt let me edit html at the moment, working on this also. But the [0] should have selected the first button I needed to edit, also checked if it has affected the other buttons, but no.

Comment: Also tried the second code, but also didnt work.

Comment: do you have any errors in the console? using the second  if you put `console.log($(this))`  above `e.preventDefault();` does returns something in the console?

Comment: No, not even a warning/error. By the way forgot to give you url of the page: https://www.kuali.co/products/kuali-ready-online-purchasing/

Comment: i see it working, its opening with the `5000` instead of the `15000` also i changed the value and its using it.

Comment: Oh my god, I cant believe, it was working all the time, and every time I was clicking scroll button to open in new window, when I clicked left mouse button, it opened and worked...Im sorry for taking your time, btw do you know why that happened?

Comment: np, the idea was to make it feel like the default right?, sorry happened what?

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading this on `$( document ).ready()` the use of Visual Composer may be resulting in the JS executing too early.  Can you try to execute your JS using `$( window ).on( 'load', function() );`?